# Anyone know how to call a feature file fromthe middle of the code - Specflow & c#

Tags: c#, specflow

Good morning / Afternoon
I have a main class that runs a lot of specific items that include calls to DB, etc.
In the middle of the code I want the code to run a list of specific feature files (specflow) but with all the previous parameters included
I have tried everything but I cannot seem to get it to work.
Anyone got some suggestions? 
Thanks 
Part of code attached

```
foreach (string element in Features) 
{
DriversPage drivers = new DriversPage(mainRun, steps); 
mainRun.TestRunNumber = dataBases.getRunNumberFromDB(); 
steps.TestRunNumber = mainRun.TestRunNumber; steps.InitializeStep(); 
drivers.InitializeDriver(element); steps.TerminateStep(); 
steps.UpdateCollections(); 

//CALL FEATURE FILE HERE!!!! 
steps.UpdateCollections(); 
}
```

Comment: You can call directly your methods bound to your scenario steps and you can pass through parameters. The only thin you can take care of that your main class stores the parameters you want to use. If I understand your problem correclty, if not please provide some example code describes your intention.

Comment: foreach (string element in Features)
                {
                    DriversPage drivers = new DriversPage(mainRun, steps);
                    mainRun.TestRunNumber = dataBases.getRunNumberFromDB();
                    steps.TestRunNumber = mainRun.TestRunNumber;
                    steps.InitializeStep();
                    drivers.InitializeDriver(element);
                    steps.TerminateStep();
                    steps.UpdateCollections();
                     //CALL FEATURE FILE HERE!!!!
                    steps.UpdateCollections();

Comment: @jorge Please add code to your question, otherwise it will be complicated to understand your problem!

Comment: Which of these your custom stuff and which calls should be Specflow code? What is your use case here?

Comment: @SayusiAndo I need to call multiple specflow features. 1st one is called: InvalidLogin.feature, and when it's called I need all the parameters from Steps, Driver and other DB parameters to be run while the feature file is also running

Comment: Are these parameters are changing during execution or they are just parameters? Have you considered using [hooks](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks)? By using hooks you can read your configuration file, so you can make your parameters available across your test execution, or just for a scenario.

Comment: @SayusiAndo, they change during execution. and I am not sure how to call the feature file. When I use new Feature.invalidlogin() nothing really happens

Comment: @SayusiAndo, right now what I want to achieve is to call the feature file from the code

Comment: You don't need the feature file. You need the class where the [bounded methods](https://specflow.org/documentation/Step-Definitions/) are. You have instantiate this class and you can invoke the method you need.